# Is this conceptually how Android resizes images within an ImageView?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-imageview

I tried following some ImageView and BitmapDrawable source code to gain a better understanding of how the two classes operate on BitMaps.  Is this generically how the process works?

I have an image which is a JPEG of size 500x500

I have ImageView A which is size 250x250, and ImageView B which is size 500x500.

Both have a BitmapDrawable which contains the JPEG

When its time to draw the Bitmap, A and B will both apply a matrix that will scale the bitmap appropriately to their respective canvas.

The JPEG itself will remain unscaled